# Error "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" during database deploy with Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy several database changes by using a database deployment job in Azure DevOps. This is after the Pipeline has successfully created a build. The database deployment job consists of the following tasks:

1. Initialize job
2. Download artifact
3. Drop Publications
4. SQL DB Deploy
5. Restore Publications copy
6. Finalize Job

Tasks 1-3 complete successfully, but task #4 breaks with the following errors:

```
==============================================================================
Task         : SQL Server database deploy
Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
Version      : 0.3.20
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://aka.ms/sqldacpacmachinegroupreadme)
==============================================================================
** Could not deploy package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [DB name] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [DB name_log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72015: The table [Table A] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
Warning SQL72015: The table [Table B] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 50 The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "[Foreign Key Name]". The conflict occurred in database "DB name", table "Table C", column 'Column name'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
USE [DB name]
[SQL script]
...
...
##[error]Publishing to database 'DB name' on server 'Server name'.
```

My question is, doesn't the SQL Server database deploy task disable foreign keys when it starts deploying? It looks like it's trying to delete the data from table "Table C", but another table (let's call it "Table D") depends on it, which makes sense, but i would think the database deploy task would disable all foreign keys when it starts dropping tables and deploying changes.

Comment: Which deploy type you are using DACPAC or SQL scripts? It seems you have to disable foreign keys before deploying.

Comment: I use DACPAC. How do i disable foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with it some yesterday, i found out the problem was something entirely different. I have a PostDeployment script in my database project and in it there was a script that was doing a DELETE. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the `SQL Server database deploy` task, correct?  Database deployment uses tool [sqlpackage.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SckKH.png), and in this case, executes the `Publish` action.  In the link, you can see all the various parameters that can be used.

In your case, I suspect you need to add `/p:IgnoreWithNocheckOnForeignKeys=True` to the `Additional Arguments` section of the task:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i do use a SQL Server deploy task. After tinkering with it some yesterday, i found out the problem was something entirely different. I have a PostDeployment script in my database project and in it there was a script that was doing a DELETE. That was the problem.